# Launching a process with arguments and profile with shark

Tags: c, macos, profiling, command-line-interface, shark

I need to sample a (cli) application with shark and pass parameters to it like so:

```
shortest-path <input-ref-littleendian|diff -u - output-ref
```

How can I do this with `shark`? Shark assumes that the parameters i need to pass to the launched cli app are for shark itself, not the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not "parameters to a program", that's a shell pipeline. You might need to use parenthesis to make it clear in which order things should happen, e.g. perhaps something like

```
$ shark ( shortest-path < input-ref-littleendian | diff -u - output-ref )
```

I don't have access to shark so I cannot verify this.

Comment: doesn't work, if i use parenthesis it doesn't recognize the `shortest-path` executable (even if i specify the path absolute). it just says it doesn't recognize the symbol after the opening `(`.

Comment: nevermind. `shark -i ./shortest-path <input-ref-littleendian > /dev/null` does the job... just wonder why i had troubles before executing this.